# Grails, Joda timepicker, hide seconds

Tags: grails, jodatime, grails-plugin, gsp, timepicker

I'm using the `joda-time-plugin` in my Grails project. In a view I set the time (LocalTime) via timepicker. Unfortunately the seconds are always displayed. The precision option just makes the seconds uneditable, so they are showed "hardcoded".

I also tried to change the Timeformat in the config.groovy but I'm not allowed to delete the seconds in the format-pattern.

This is the code from my view:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: dailyBookingInstance, field: 'start', 'error')} required">
    <label for="start">
        <g:message code="dailyBooking.start.label" default="Start" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <joda:timePicker name="start" value="${dailyBookingInstance?.start}" ></joda:timePicker>
</div>
```

Thats the part in my config.groovy I tried to change:

```
jodatime {
    format.org.joda.time.DateTime = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    format.org.joda.time.LocalDate = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    format.org.joda.time.LocalTime = "HH:mm:ss"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the plugin code and this is not possible because it is hard coded in the plugin tag library.

To achieve this, you need to create your own tag library extent it from plugin tag library and remove that hard coded second section.

I have tried this, following is my code, have a look--

**some view**

```
<joda:timePickerNoSec name="end" value="" default="none" noSelection="['': '']"/>
```

**TestTagLib.groovy**

```
class TestTagLib extends DateTimeTagLib {
    def timePickerNoSec = { attrs ->
        log.debug '***** joda:timePickerNoSec *****'
        def fields = [DateTimeFieldType.hourOfDay(), DateTimeFieldType.minuteOfHour()]
        myRenderPicker(fields, attrs)
    }

    def myRenderPicker = { List fields, attrs ->
        def precision = attrs.precision ?: (grailsApplication.config.grails.tags.datePicker.default.precision ?: 'minute')
        log.debug "precision = $precision"

        log.debug "fields = $fields"
        switch (precision) {
            case 'year': fields.remove(DateTimeFieldType.monthOfYear())
            case 'month': fields.remove(DateTimeFieldType.dayOfMonth())
            case 'day': fields.remove(DateTimeFieldType.hourOfDay())
            case 'hour': fields.remove(DateTimeFieldType.minuteOfHour())
            case 'minute': fields.remove(DateTimeFieldType.secondOfMinute())
        }
        log.debug "fields = $fields"

        def defaultValue = attrs.'default'
        if (!defaultValue) {
            defaultValue = new DateTime()
        } else if (defaultValue == 'none') {
            defaultValue = null
        } else if (defaultValue instanceof String) {
            defaultValue = getParser(fields).parseDateTime(defaultValue)
        } else if (!(defaultValue instanceof ReadableInstant) && !(defaultValue instanceof ReadablePartial)) {
            throwTagError("Tag [datePicker] requires the default date to be a parseable String or instanceof ReadableInstant or ReadablePartial")
        }
        log.debug "default = $defaultValue"

        def value = attrs.value
        if (value == 'none') {
            value = null
        } else if (!value) {
            value = defaultValue
        }
        log.debug "value = $value"

        def name = attrs.name
        def id = attrs.id ?: name

        def noSelection = attrs.noSelection
        if (noSelection) {
            noSelection = noSelection.entrySet().iterator().next()
        }

        def years = attrs.years

        def dfs = new DateFormatSymbols(RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request))

        if (!years) {
            def tempyear = null
            if (value && value?.isSupported(DateTimeFieldType.year())) tempyear = value.year
            else tempyear = new LocalDate().year
            years = (tempyear - (grailsApplication.config.grails.tags.datePicker.default.yearsBelow ?: 100))..(tempyear + (grailsApplication.config.grails.tags.datePicker.default.yearsAbove ?: 100))
        }

        log.debug "starting rendering"
        out << "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"struct\" />"

        // create day select
        if (fields.contains(DateTimeFieldType.dayOfMonth())) {
            log.debug "rendering day"
            out.println "<select name=\"${name}_day\" id=\"${id}_day\">"

            if (noSelection) {
                renderNoSelectionOption(noSelection.key, noSelection.value, value?.dayOfMonth)
                out.println()
            }

            for (i in 1..31) {
                out << "<option value=\"${i}\""
                if (i == value?.dayOfMonth) {
                    out << " selected=\"selected\""
                }
                out.println ">${i}</option>"
            }
            out.println '</select>'
        }

        // create month select
        if (fields.contains(DateTimeFieldType.monthOfYear())) {
            log.debug "rendering month"
            out.println "<select name=\"${name}_month\" id=\"${id}_month\">"

            if (noSelection) {
                renderNoSelectionOption(noSelection.key, noSelection.value, value?.monthOfYear)
                out.println()
            }

            dfs.months.eachWithIndex { m, i ->
                if (m) {
                    def monthIndex = i + 1
                    out << "<option value=\"${monthIndex}\""
                    if (monthIndex == value?.monthOfYear) out << " selected=\"selected\""
                    out << '>'
                    out << m
                    out.println '</option>'
                }
            }
            out.println '</select>'
        }

        // create year select
        if (fields.contains(DateTimeFieldType.year())) {
            log.debug "rendering year"
            out.println "<select name=\"${name}_year\" id=\"${id}_year\">"

            if (noSelection) {
                renderNoSelectionOption(noSelection.key, noSelection.value, value?.year)
                out.println()
            }

            for (i in years) {
                out << "<option value=\"${i}\""
                if (i == value?.year) {
                    out << " selected=\"selected\""
                }
                out.println ">${i}</option>"
            }
            out.println '</select>'
        }

        // do hour select
        if (fields.contains(DateTimeFieldType.hourOfDay())) {
            log.debug "rendering hour"
            out.println "<select name=\"${name}_hour\" id=\"${id}_hour\">"

            if (noSelection) {
                renderNoSelectionOption(noSelection.key, noSelection.value, value?.hourOfDay)
                out.println()
            }

            for (i in 0..23) {
                def h = i.toString().padLeft(2, '0')
                out << "<option value=\"${h}\""
                if (value?.hourOfDay == i) out << " selected=\"selected\""
                out << '>' << h << '</option>'
                out.println()
            }
            out.println '</select> :'

            // If we're rendering the hour, but not the minutes, then display the minutes and seconds as 00 in read-only format
            if (!fields.contains(DateTimeFieldType.minuteOfHour())) {
                out.println '00:00'
            }
        }

        // do minute select
        if (fields.contains(DateTimeFieldType.minuteOfHour())) {
            log.debug "rendering minute"
            out.println "<select name=\"${name}_minute\" id=\"${id}_minute\">"

            if (noSelection) {
                renderNoSelectionOption(noSelection.key, noSelection.value, value?.minuteOfHour)
                out.println()
            }

            for (i in 0..59) {
                def m = i.toString().padLeft(2, '0')
                out << "<option value=\"${m}\""
                if (value?.minuteOfHour == i) out << " selected=\"selected\""
                out << '>' << m << '</option>'
                out.println()
            }
//            out.println '</select> :'
            out.println '</select>'

            // If we're rendering the minutes, but not the seconds, then display the seconds as 00 in read-only format
//            if (!fields.contains(DateTimeFieldType.secondOfMinute())) {
//                out.println '00'
//            }
        }

        // do second select
        if (fields.contains(DateTimeFieldType.secondOfMinute())) {
            log.debug "rendering second"
            out.println "<select name=\"${name}_second\" id=\"${id}_second\">"

            if (noSelection) {
                renderNoSelectionOption(noSelection.key, noSelection.value, value?.secondOfMinute)
                out.println()
            }

            for (i in 0..59) {
                def s = i.toString().padLeft(2, '0')
                out << "<option value=\"${s}\""
                if (value?.secondOfMinute == i) out << " selected=\"selected\""
                out << '>' << s << '</option>'
                out.println()
            }
            out.println '</select>'
        }

        // do zone select
        if (attrs.useZone == "true") {
            out << dateTimeZoneSelect(name: "${name}_zone")
        }

        log.debug "done"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps..,.

Comment: Hi thanks! I just tried to comment the regarding if statement. But it didnt change anything. Do I have to create my own library?

Comment: Are you using `joda:timePickerNoSec` tag, as in my answer?

Comment: No, I tried just to comment/delete if (!fields.contains(DateTimeFieldType.minuteOfHour())) {out.println '00:00'} in the original taglib

Comment: No, you need to comment one if statement in-side `fields.contains(DateTimeFieldType.minuteOfHour` if statement.
Or Just copy paste my lag lib and use `joda:timePickerNoSec` tag.